# JavaScript append elements from function to sender

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function OnChildStateChangeXML(sender) {
return function () {
var folderContent = '';
var data = xhttp.responseXML;
var folders = data.getElementsByTagName("directory");
for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
                        folderContent += "<li onclick='PopulateChild(this)'>" + folders[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</li>";
...
...
    }
  }
}
```

Sender is a list item element inside an unordered list.

Is it possible to attach generated folderContent to sender as list items inside new list below sender?

It would look like this:

```
li
li
li *sender*
    li folderContent1
    li folderContent2
    ...
li
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Append a ul to t and append the lis to that new ul.

Comment: Can you clarify the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a ul and append the lis to that ul.

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.innerHTML = folderContent;
sender.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: Pretty obvious, but still.